# Is there an upper bound for total variation distance to uniform in terms of the mean?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, total-variation

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be non-increasing with $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = 1$ and $\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)\,dx := \mu \in [0,1].$

Is there a nice upper bound for $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x) - 1|\,dx$ in terms of $\mu$? If so, is there an $f$ for which the bound is tight? Thinking of $f$ as a probability density on $[0,1]$ with mean $\mu$, this would give an upper bound on (twice) the total variation distance between the $f$ distribution and the uniform distribution.

Comment: I think your "non-increasing" density forces $\mu \le \frac12$, and when $\mu=\frac12$ then forces a uniform distribution.

Comment: If investigating this, I would play with the point where $f(x)-1$ changes sign.  For example if $f(x)=0$ for $x > 2\mu$ and $f(x)=\frac1{2\mu}$ for $x < 2\mu$ then I think your integral would be $2 -4\mu$

Comment: @Henry Yes, and it seems intuitive that the distribution you give is the worst case, though I haven't been able to prove that.